# my codes for loop isn't increasing.

Tags: ios

I intend to find out prime numbers until N. My codes outer for loop isn't increasing. The answer is printed out to be 2 in this case.

```
let limit = Int(readLine()!)! 
    var factors = 2          // as prime no.s only have 2 factors
    var countFactors = 0    
    var prime = [Int]()      //array to store prime nos

    for number in 2..<limit {       // to count from 2 till N

        for i in 1...number {

            if(number%i == 0){
            countFactors += 1
            }
        }
        if(countFactors == factors){
            prime.append(n)
        }
    }

    for items in prime {
        print(items)
    }
```

Comment: What is `readLine()` ?? BTW why you using double loop??

Comment: And what is prime.append(n), you want to append the number or not?

Comment: What is readLine() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your code doesn't compile. You probably mean

```
prime.append(number)
```

2) The *unexpected behavior* occurs because you forgot to reset `countFactors` in each iteration of the outer loop

```
...
for number in 2..<limit {       // to count from 2 till N
    countFactors = 0
    for i in 1...number {
...
```